# Where do I set "Company" information for a Facebook App?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Where do I specify my `company` node information when setting up or updating an existing Facebook app?

When viewed via the Graph API Explorer, an older app my company created has the node `company`.  However, more recent apps my company created do not have the `company` node when using the Graph API Explorer.

Is this something removed/deprecated from the Facebook app setup process?